# Is it possible to add count(*) and groupBy to Spring Data Jpa Specification?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I'm writing an app using Spring Boot and Spring Data Jpa.

I have a method which uses RSQL (I use [this](https://github.com/perplexhub/rsql-jpa-specification) library) and Specification to make a filter call with where clauses to the db.

My repository:

```java
public interface BaseRepository<M extends BaseModel> extends JpaRepository<M, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<M>{

}
```

In the service I make a call to the repository:

```java
String filter = "createdDate > 2019-09-04T11:52:59.449";
return repository.findAll(toSpecification(filter), pageable).getContent();
```

So I use the library above to generate a Specification and pass it to the repository.

Now I need to group a result by some fields.

The question how to add **count** and **groupBy** to a specification? Or maybe I need to create a predicate where I define this **count** and **groupBy** (somehow) and make a specification out of this? What is a better way to do it?

**UPDATE #0**

I've managed to add a group by section to the result sql query. I create a new specification object where I define all the group by parameters and then combine this specification with the original one.

```java
String filter = "createdDate > 2019-09-04T11:52:59.449";

Specification<M> groupBySpec = new Specification<M>() {

            @Override
            public Predicate toPredicate(Root<M> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

                List<Expression<?>> groupByParams = new ArrayList<>();

                groupByParams.add(root.get("param1"));
                groupByParams.add(root.get("param2"));

                query.groupBy(groupByParams);

                return query.getGroupRestriction();
            }
        };


return repository.findAll(groupBySpec.and(toSpecification(filter)), pageable).getContent();
```

The thing is it always selects all the columns but I need to select only those which are in the group by section.

As a result I get a sql exception: `ERROR: column "columnName" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`.

I've tried to use multiselect like this `criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get("column1"), root.get("column2")).distinct(true).getGroupRestriction();` but it selects all the columns anyway.

It works if I use `@Query("query")` where I define which columns to select but I need it to work using Criteria Api/Specification.

Comment: What are you grouping by and can you give us a snippet of the Class you're querying.

Comment: @locus2k It should be possible to group by different fields which are grabbed from a request http param (e.g. orderBy = field1, field2, field3). That's actually how it works for filter (I have a http param filter = field1, field2.... which I parse) which is used to create where clauses for a sql query (a static string in the question is used just for an example). And the Class I'm trying to query is quite simple: it just contains a number of fields and it doesn't have any relationships with other models.

Comment: i ask because it looks like RSQL only applies to the `WHERE` clause for filtering, not for grouping. Spring can do `groupBy` but you have to write the query for it which requires to know the field to query

Comment: @locus2k Yes, I understand that RSQL only applies to the `WHERE`. The question is how to add group by to the result specification which is already generated by the library. What kind of query are you talking exactly about?

Comment: You can add a jqpl query to do a count normally like `SELECT Count(m.id), m.type from MyClass M WHERE m.foo = ?1 GroupBy m.type' to your spring query repository but that would require knowing the fields.

Comment: @locus2k That's the point. I don't know these fields during compilation. I retrieve them on runtime.

Comment: I see now. Might check out https://spring.io/blog/2011/04/26/advanced-spring-data-jpa-specifications-and-querydsl/ to see if it provides how to do what you want.

Answer (score 6):

You can create your own `GroupBySpecification` class which adds a a groupBy expression to an other specification:

```
public class GroupBySpecification implements Specification {
  Specification original;
  Parameters parameters; // whatever data needed for calculating groupBy expression

  public GroupBySpecification(Specification original, Parameters parameters){
      this.original = original;
      this.parameters = parameters;
  }
  public Predicate toPredicate(Root<T> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {

      Expression<?> expression = ...; // whatever logic needed to be used on parameters...
      criteriaBuilder.groupBy(expression);
      return original.toPredicate(root, query, criteriabuilder);
  }
```

}

Then you can use it like this:

```
String filter = "createdDate > 2019-09-04T11:52:59.449";
return repository.findAll(new GroupBySpecification(toSpecification(filter),parameters),
   pageable).getContent();
```

if you need **count** then call the appropriate repository method:

```
repository.count(new GroupBySpecification(toSpecification(filter),parameters));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I've done the same but instead of creating a separate class for a specification, I create a new specification object in my service and then combine it using **and** method from a specification class (`specObject.and(anotherSpecObject)`). Will update my question to include this.
Regarding **repository.count()** method. Not sure that it's what I need because it returns just a number of models from a result list and I need it work as an **aggregate function** (like count(*) and it appends one more column to the result set).

Comment: Although I've another issue using this approach. Despite the fact that I've added group by to the result sql query I need to specify specific columns to return which are used in group by section otherwise I get a sql exception `ERROR: column "columnName" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. I've tried to use CriteriaQuery's method *multiselect* but it selects all the columns anyway. So need to find out how to select specific columns using Criteria Api because it works fine if I use _@Query("query")_ but that's not my case.

Comment: @Coffemanz i'm in the same situation i need an aggregate custom object with count() but it seems impossible this way. I don't know it it's even possiblee

Answer (score 2):

This cannot be done. Specifications are supposed to an abstraction only on the WHERE clause. It's similar to QueryDSLPredicateExecutor. The better approach here might be to use queryDSL or criteriaAPI to create the dynamic query you want to create. You can use a combination of the two to work it out.

Check - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2361#issuecomment-986922491